# how to get sub iframes in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

How can I get the **iframe** inside of **iframe**?

Now target webpage is containing **iframe** and there is another **iframe** inside of the main **iframe**.

But `page.frames() and page.mainFrame().childFrames()` just returning the main **iframe**.

iframe->iframe ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just navigate through the childs array.
`mainFrame` doesn't refer to your first iFrame but the page itself, which is considered a frame.

```js
page.frames()[0].childFrames()
```

Comment: Take a look at [this test](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/60567575d27c6fd9294044b397cef59a178fe06a/test/frame.spec.js#L71) and how it uses [this function](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/60567575d27c6fd9294044b397cef59a178fe06a/test/utils.js#L137) to navigate [these frames](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/test/assets/frames/nested-frames.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. )
But I get the target element by using is

          const mainIframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
          const captchaItem = mainIframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector(
            'iframe'

Comment: If your frame is an elementHandle (a frame you got using evaluate or $) you can call the `contentFrame` function which will give you the Frame object.

Comment: Yes, seems this is a solution too. But which one is better?